# how to shade portion of a circle using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

[image]
Could you show how to shade regions within circles using tikz?

Answer (score 5):

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (5);
\draw[thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5);

\node[draw, circle, thick, fill=white, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=0, label=225:O] at (0,0) {};


\draw[->, -{Stealth}] (6,0) -- (9,0);

\begin{scope}[xshift=15cm]
\path[clip, preaction={draw, thick}] (0,0) circle (5);
\fill[draw=black, thick, pattern=north west lines] (-5,2) -- (3,2) -- (3,-5) -- (-5,-5) -- cycle;
\fill[draw=black, thick, pattern=north west lines] (3,5) -- (3,2) -- (5,2) -- (5,5) -- cycle;

\node[draw, circle, thick, fill=black, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=0, label=225:O] at (0,0) {};
\draw[dashed] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[dashed] (0,-5) -- (0,5);

\draw[<->] (.5,2.3) -- (2.5,2.3) node[midway, above] {3cm};
\draw[<->] (3.3,1.7) -- (3.3,.2) node[midway, right] {2cm};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option: Draw a colored circle and use the circle as clipping path for two white rectangles

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] circle (5cm);
\begin{scope}
\clip circle (5cm);
\draw[fill=white] (3,2) rectangle ++(5,5);
\draw[fill=white] (3,2) rectangle ++(-8,-8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without clipping (so a bit more work) using angles and arcs:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em,>=stealth]
\tikzmath{%
  integer \x, \y;
  \r = 5;
  \x = 3; \y = 2;
  \a = asin(\y/\r);
  \b = acos(\x/\r);
}
\draw circle [radius=\r];
\draw [gray, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=gray]
   (\x,\y) -- (\a:\r) arc (\a:\b:\r) -- (-\b:\r) arc (-\b:-180-\a:\r) -- cycle;
\draw [dashed] (-\r,0) -- (\r,0) (0,-\r) -- (0,\r);
\fill circle [radius=0.125] node [below left] {$O$};
\fill [fill=gray] (\x, \y) circle [radius=0.125] 
  node [above left] {$(\x,\y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]